# Detach() and offsetUnset() difference in SPLObjecStorage

Tags: php, spl

what is the diffrenece between Detach() and offsetUnset() in SPLObjecStorage. Looks like they do same thing. if so why there is two method for same job?

Comment: `offsetUnset()` is an alias of `detach()`.  `detach()` is the canonical method to use, but `offsetUnset()` is there as part of the `ArrayAccess` interface implementation to allow `unset($storage[$offset])`.

Comment: @salathe That explains well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference, one [is an alias](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splobjectstorage.offsetunset.php) for the other:

> Note:
>
> SplObjectStorage::offsetUnset() is an alias of
>   SplObjectStorage::detach().